# how to stringify a string to javascript backquote

Tags: javascript, string

Is there a way to safely stringify a string to a javascript backquote string?

example:

```js
function stringToDoubleQuote(str: string) {
  return JSON.stringify(str)
}

function stringToBackQuote(str: string) {
  // ...
}
```

test:

```js
const quotelist = `- 'singlequote'
- "doublequote"
- \`backquote\`
- template: ...\${0}...$\{1}...`
console.log('(A)', stringToDoubleQuote(quotelist))
console.log('(B)', stringToBackQuote(quotelist))
```

expected output:

```
(A) "- 'singlequote'\n- \"doublequote\"\n- `backquote`\n- template: ...${0}...${1}..."
(B) `- 'singlequote'
- "doublequote"
- \`backquote\`
- template: ...\${0}...\${1}...`
```

#### Use case

My goal is to create a module that transforms css files into js files, I want to keep the output file readable and not be a long line full of \n, hence the use of backquotes.

for example, this css code:

```css
body {
  color: fuchsia;
  background: khaki;
}
main{
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

must not be transformed into this:

```js
const styleElement = document.createElement('style')
document.head.append(style)
styleElement.append( /* css */ "body {\n  color: fuchsia;\n  background: khaki;\n}\nmain{\n  margin: 2em;\n  padding: 1em;\n}")
```

but this easy-to-read code:

```js
const styleElement = document.createElement('style')
document.head.append(style)
styleElement.append( /* css */ `body {
  color: fuchsia;
  background: khaki;
}
main{
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
}`)
```

Comment: Both the strings are *the same*. There aren't any runtime artefacts to tell you whether something was escaped in the literal version or not. The string literal is only there when you write the code. Once processed, it creates a string with given content. And that's it - there is no link back to the literal or wherever the string content came from. This seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). What is the intent there? Why should you differentiate the same string?

Comment: @VLAZ My goal is to create a module that transforms css files into js files, I want to keep the output file readable and not be a long line full of `\n`, hence the use of backquotes.

Comment: If you want to transform source code, that's different to just handling some strings.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had tried to simplify my question for clarity, but I failed. I've just modified it by specifying my use case.

Comment: [Maybe useful](https://github.com/KooiInc/LifeCSS)

Comment: @vladZams No, the target output is not a file. It's a (template) string literal inside a JS file.

Comment: @vladZams Yes, OP wants to produce a JS file, and include the CSS file content as the value of a (template) string literal in that JS code. Which requires string escaping, not just copying.

Answer (score 2):

There is no builtin you can use (like `JSON.stringify`), but you can easily build this yourself by escaping `` ` ``, `\` and `${`:

```
function stringToBackQuote(str: string): string {
  return '`' + str.replace(/`|\\|\$\{/g, '\\$&') + '`';
}
```

```js
const stringToDoubleQuote = JSON.stringify;
function stringToBackQuote(str) {
  return '`' + str.replace(/`|\\|\$\{/g, '\\$&') + '`';
}
const quotelist = `- 'singlequote'
- "doublequote"
- \`backquote\`
- \\bashslash\\
- template: ...\${0}...$\{1}...`
console.log('(A)', stringToDoubleQuote(quotelist))
console.log('(B)', stringToBackQuote(quotelist))
console.log('(C)', quotelist)
```

Comment: are `\`` and `${` the only sequence to escape?

Comment: @Yukulélé Whoops, no, I forgot to escape backslashes themselves! But [those are the three relevant ones](https://262.ecma-international.org/14.0/#prod-TemplateCharacter).

Comment: @Yukulélé Potentially you may also want to escape `\r` characters if you need to preserve `\r\n` linebreaks, as in template strings those all become just `\n`.

Comment: Indeed, I expect that `eval(stringToBackQuote(str))` always equals `str` whatever its value.

Comment: @Yukulélé Unfortunately, this solution fails to replicate the character at [line:9:24] of its source code.

Source: [$\].
Output: [\$] (that is the inversion of the source)

However, it matches the expected output in the OP. Yukulélé can you confirm there is no a typo in the expected output that you have shared originally?   
By now I'm confused... meaning, not sure what's the expected output (i. e. what's the exact problem we're solving).

Comment: And as mentioned by VLAZ, there is no way at runtime to differentiate between the source string [ $\{ ] and a source string [ \${ ], since at runtime they are identical: each of them has a length of 2 and consists of characters [ $ ] and [ { ].

Comment: @Bergi thanks for clarifying the problem – generating a JS that, after being interpreted by a browser, produces the original source)! The suggested regex works with no issues, even when we have the $\{ sequence (if we read it from a file as opposed to using JS string as an input – that made me confused). Upvoted.